# Does there exist a $\mathbb{C}$- differentiable function in neighbourhood of $0$ such that $f(1/n)=(-1)^n \cdot \frac{1}{n}$, $n=1,2,\dots$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis

Does there exist a $\mathbb{C}$- differentiable function in neighbourhood of $0$ such that $f(1/n)=(-1)^n \cdot \frac{1}{n}$, $n=1,2,\dots$

My attempt:

Since we want $f$ to be differentiable at $0$, then it is continuous at $0$. So if we take a sequence $(a_n)\rightarrow0$ then must be $f(a_n)\rightarrow f(0)$. Having said that, take a sequence $(b_n):=1/n$, $(n=1,2,\dots )$. It obviously converges to $0$. Now consider a sequence $f(b_n)=(-1)^n \cdot \frac{1}{n}$. It also converges to $0$. So definition of $f$ doesn't contradict continuity at $0$. So there may be a chance of finding such a function.

Define $g$ that is equal to $f$ for $n=1,2,\dots$ and $0$ elsewhere.
 Calculate:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{g(0+\frac{1}{n})-g(0)}{1/n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(\frac{1}{n})-0}{1/n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{(-1)^n \cdot \frac{1}{n}}{1/n}\rightarrow 0$$

So $g$ is such a function. Is that ok?

Comment: Look again at your last limit. Does it really converge to zero? And if not, might that suggest a problem with any such $f$?

Comment: Hint: after seeing that you must have $f(0)=0$, consider $h(z) = \frac{f(z)}{z}$.

Comment: Oh my bad. Limit obviously doesn't exist. Hmm  i don't know now..And i think this isnt enough, since I was checking only $R$-differentiabiltiy i guess ;/

Comment: What is f(z) here Daniel?

Comment: There is no such function, by identity theorem.

Comment: how it is so? can't that be shwoed without refering to this theorem?

Comment: The sequence ${ f({1 \over n}) - f(0) \over {1 \over n} } = (-1)^n$, so it cannot have a limit.

Comment: I know. And also that would prove only real differentiability of such function yes?

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose that such an $f$ exists. As you've pointed out, in order to be differentiable in a neighborhood of $0,$ $f$ must in particular be continuous at $0,$ and this can only happen if $f(0)=0.$

Now, since $f$ is differentiable in a neighborhood of $0,$ then $f'(0)$ exists--that is, $$\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{f(z)-f(0)}{z-0}=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{f(z)}{z}$$ exists. But if we consider $b_n$ as you've defined, we see that $$\frac{f(b_n)}{b_n}=(-1)^n$$ for all $n\ge1,$ which shows that it is *impossible* for $f'(0)$ to exist (since the limit must be independent of the approach we take to the origin), and we have a contradiction.

Thus, no such $f$ exists.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it:

First focus on the even $n$. Let $g(z) = z$. Since

$$
f\left( \frac{1}{2n} \right) = \frac{1}{2n} = g\left( \frac{1}{2n} \right),
$$
we see that $f$ and $g$ agree on a set with an accumulation point. Hence, the identity theorem implies that $f = g$ everywhere (where $f$ is holomorphic). But this contradicts the given equality for odd $n$.